# How to get the nearby 5 to 8 wifi record

Tags: flutter

I want to implement a feature to get and record nearby Wi-Fi SSID and signal lists. I found that the `wifi_info_flutter`plugin was outdated. Which plugin or method can do the same feature? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `wifi_scan` can do that. Thank you very for all comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 packages: [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)
and [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus)

```
final ConnectivityResult connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  // Get the Wi-Fi's SSID
  final String ssid = await NetworkInfo().getWifiName();

  print('Wi-Fi SSID: $ssid');

} else {
  print('Device not connected');
}
```

Comment: I found that the network_info_plus can get wifi name. Is it can get nearly wifi list? Thank you.

Comment: If you use the pakage `network_info_plus` then also you could get the wifi list.

Comment: `network_info_plus` only can get the currently connected wifi info, but thank you for your comment.